# facebooker 2 - javascript callback after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, facebooker2

I've been using the following gem for facebook inttegration in my rails app  - 
https://github.com/dekart/facebooker2.git

I've had a few issues with it , so I've decided to try and upgrade to the latest version of the main facebooker gem.
 - https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2.git

My issue is that I can't seem to do callbacks with the new gem
previously I could do something like this -

```
   <%= fb_login(:text=>t('my_text')) do %>
          $("#myForm").submit();
          top.location.href='<%= APP_CONFIG[:somewhere] %>';
   <% end %>
```

It's not working in the new gem and I can't see how to do it in the docs.

Is it possible to do a javascript callback with the new facebooker2 gem?

---

I've managed to get the js working by doing this -

```
    <%- fb_login { concat " $('#myForm').submit();" }%>
```

however I can't seem to add text. This throws an error -

```
  <%- fb_login :text=>t('my text'), { concat " $('#myForm').submit();" }%>
```

I'm sure this is just a syntax thing. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: <%- fb_login(:text=>t('my text')) { concat " $('#myForm').submit();" }%>

Answer (score 0):

Try using a scriplet instead of an expression in the first line:

```
<% fb_login(:text=>t('my_text')) do %>
      $("#myForm").submit();
      top.location.href='<%= APP_CONFIG[:somewhere] %>';
<% end %>
```

Comment: I spoke too soon that seems to render everything twice for some reason. I get 2 facebook login buttons rendering.